# Dirt coming into Washing machine

Tags: washing-machine

When I do a heavy load in my washing machine like with a big towel load or a quilt, I find dirt on the bottom of the washing machine. Where is it coming from and how do I get rid of it.

Comment: How dirty was the quilt? More importantly, if you fill a bucket with house water do you find silt/sediment on the bottom of the bucket?

Comment: @JonCuster I live in NYC so we have pretty clean water.

Comment: Is this a recent development? Was there plumbing work done in the building?

Comment: no there are 2 machines in the laundry room and just this one has the problem

Comment: Hmmmm… I’d try running an empty load. The expeller pump could be failing for example. Vacuuming out the crud might help.